# Can you filter on device in Softlayer URL?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to pass a filter for device name into https://control.softlayer.com/devices.  The reason for this is to post a message to Slack for our team with just that group of machines (with a similar name).  I'm expecting it to be something like:

https://control.softlayer.com/devices?name=

Then I'm expecting when the user click on that, they come to the device list page with the filter of "Device Name: something" already applied.

Answer (score 0):

sorry that is not possible.

Regards